# Want to remove attribute array in my response Laravel api

Tags: json, laravel, api, response

This is my code. I just want to remove attribute array from message because I’m not fetching error on my frontend on angular and andriod app.

```
public function createCountry(Request $coun)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($coun->all(), [
        'country_name' => 'required|unique:countries,country_name|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
    ]);
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['code' => 400, 'message' => $validate->errors()], 400);
    } else {
        $country = Country::create([
            'country_name' => $coun->input('country_name'),
        ]);
        return response()->json(['code' => 201, 'message' => 'Country Created Successfully',
            'object' => $country], 201);
    }
}
```

This is my response

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": {
        "country_name": [
            "The country name already exist.",
            "The country name format is invalid."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiya, which array are you talking about please?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. However, if you're not displaying the error message in your client (Angular or Android), either don't bother performing your validation on the server (bad idea) or check the response and if it contains errors for `country_name` ignore them?

Comment: Actually, I want to remove this country_name I want my response like this

{
    "code": 400,
    "message": {
            "The country name already exist.",
            "The country name format is invalid."
    }
}

just code and Message in error @Peppermintology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking to return the error messages without their keys, then you want to use the [`all()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html#method_all) method available on the [`MessageBag`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html) object.

```
public function createCountry(Request $coun)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($coun->all(), [
        'country_name' => 'required|unique:countries,country_name|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        // Note the use of all() after calling the errors() method
        return response()->json(['code' => 400, 'message' => $validate->errors()->all()], 400);
    }

    $country = Country::create([
        'country_name' => $coun->input('country_name'),
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'code' => 201, 'message' => 'Country Created Successfully',
        'object' => $country
    ], 201);
}
```

This will result in the keys being omitted from the response:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": [
        "The country name already exist.",
        "The country name format is invalid."
    ]
}
```

**Update 1**

If you don't want the array brackets included for a single error message, then you could do the following:

```
if ($validate->fails()) {
    $messages = $validate->errors()->count() > 1 ? $validate->errors()->all() : $validate->errors()->first();
    return response()->json(['code' => 400, 'message' => $messages], 400);
}
```

Comment: i want to remove this arraylist on message object
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": [
        "The country name already exist."
    ]
}
@peppermintology

Comment: @SAHServices What if there is more than one error?

Comment: I will manage that but let me how can I remove array i just want code:400, "message" : { Name Field is Required
}
 @peppermintology

Comment: @SAHServices I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thank You soo much @peppermintology Your are very helpful person and very cooperative Thank you so very much